# Swagger yaml define a new field with type string and a default not null value

Tags: yaml, swagger

In swagger.yaml `swagger: "2.0"`, how do I define a new field let's call it `test` which is a `string` and have a default value of `abc`?

I'm working on a legacy project with many object definitions on the swagger.yaml. This yaml file together with a maven plugin then will produce auto generated java objects.

Just trying to trace one of the auto generated object.

```
OrganizationResource:
    type: "object"
    required:
      - "data"
    properties:
      data:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Organization"
      testa:
          type: "string"
          value: "abc"
    description: "Resource container for Organization"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `default` keyword to specify the default values.

```yaml
      test:
        type: string
        default: abc
```